# How do database joins work in a distributed relational database?

Tags: sql, database, distributed

From my own research, I understand the basic idea behind SQL join algorithms on a single database (non-distributed) - eg. hash join, merge join, loop join. Are distributed join algorithms similar to the ones on a non-distributed database?

For example, if I have a Users table with the attributes:
 - User_id
 - Age

And I have a Comments table with the attributes:
 - User_id
 - Comment_id
 - Comment

Suppose the distributed database uses the User_id for sharding the Users table and uses the Comment_id for sharding the Comments table.

So what actually happens when you call a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN Comments ON Users.User_id = Comments.User_id
```

? Is the User table and Comment table collated onto a single machine and then the JOIN is performed? Or is there just some way which you can do a JOIN even though it is distributed?

Comment: Remember that sharding is just one partition strategy among a myriad of others. Are you specifically asking about sharding, or partitioning in general?

Comment: I suppose partitioning in general, but I am familiar with sharding so an example based on sharding would be great!

Comment: this article may help as it explains multiple approaches with their pros and cons: https://www.singlestore.com/blog/scaling-distributed-joins/

Answer (score 7):

This is a high-level answer.

In a distributed environment, there are a handful of approaches to `JOIN`s.

1. Broadcast joins.  One table is replicated and sent to all processing nodes, each of which has part of a larger table.  The canonical use case is a large table with a small reference table.
2. Hash joins where both tables have the same partitioning key.  In this case, the join can be done locally, because all the relevant data is already co-located.
3. Hash joins based on the partitioning key of one table.  The second table is hashed and the data sent to the appropriate nodes.  This then reverts to (2).
4. A full hash join where the data for both tables is hashed and sent to nodes where it is collocated.

Note that the word "hash" here is intended to be generic.  If the partitioning is based on data ranges, then that is an example of a hash function.

Once the data is sent to a particular node, then some other `JOIN` algorithm is used -- which could be hash-based, sort-based, or index-based (if the distributed data also supports indexes; many do not).

In addition, there may be tweaks on the algorithms to handle "larger-than-memory" results and data skew in the `JOIN` keys.

A more detailed answer could probably fill multiple chapters in a book.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I'm still a little confused about the JOINs you have mentioned. In Broadcast Join, what do you mean by "One table is replicated and sent to all processing nodes"? Taking the User and Comment example in my question, suppose the tables are split up into multiple machines - Machine 1 has part 1 of the User table, Machine 2 has part 2 of the User Table, Machine 3 has part 1 of the Comments table, Machine 4 has part 2 of the Comments Table. Are you saying that the User table is reconstructed in one of the Machines (either 1 or 2), and then sent over to Machines 3 & 4?

Comment: And once it is sent over to Machine 3 & 4, a local JOIN is performed. Then, the result is collated in a single machine, and then the result is returned?

Comment: @Ryn . . . This is really a quite broad subject, one that cannot easily be explained in a Q&A forum or comments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Cmon, you should have given it a try at least. It's a very interesting matter but most of answers I've seen to far are quite vague. Kudos to anyone who has a hands-on experience of cross-host joins of a sharded db and can explain things. If one fails to explain a subject, it means he doesn't understand it...